# How to pass parameters to built in Windows commands via AutoHotKey?

Tags: windows, file, cmd, autohotkey

I'm trying to create a simple file merge tool to combine split log file in to a text file.

```
FileSelectFolder, folder, \\Myserver\Data\
InputBox, filename, Save File,Please type the name you will call the merged file.`n The file will be saved in the folder "merged" of the same root directory as its "part files" are located., , , , , , , ,merged_file.txt
if errorlevel = 1
exitApp
IfExist, %folder%\merged\%filename%
MsgBox, 4, File Overwrite -or- Append?, The file already exists.  Do you want to append to this file?  `nNote:  If you select "No" the existing file will be replaced during this process.
ifmsgbox, no
FileDelete %folder%\merged\%filename%
FileCreateDir, %folder%\merged
IfExist %folder%\merged\%filename%_file_list.txt
FileDelete %folder%\merged\%filename%_file_list.txt
Runwait, %COMSPEC% /c copy /k %folder%\*.log %folder%\merged\%filename% 
ExitApp
```

I did not want to use AHK **fileread** and **fileappend** as log file are quite big ~40mb.

The above code does not yield any errors but does not produce any file either.
I tried adding " to the parameters with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Okay one more shot here!

As it turns out you do need to quote your Path in command string for use with COMSPEC.

I also correctly stated earlier that there is no /K switch or option for the Copy command. There is Compsec switch /K which Keeps the Terminal Open and a /c which means Close Terminal.

Also your syntax is wrong with Copy. In order to Concatenate a file with Copy you need to do something like this:

```
Copy mergedfile.txt+file2merge.txt newmergedfile.txt
```

But I suggest you use Type to Concatenate a text file instead:

```
RunWait, %COMSPEC% /c type "%folder%\*.log" >> "%folder%\merged\%filename%"
```

Comment: Yeah, looks like there is no /k switch for the copy command. Took that out, maybe it will work now. Have you looked into the AHK equivalent command FileCopy?

Comment: i tried FileAppend and FileCopy unfortunately the files im trying to merge are too big for FileRead to store in memory and append using FileAppend. With FileCopy it only copies one file as the merged file , does not append all the files in the folder as one big file.

Comment: Alright this time I tested it out, it works, found the best method to Concatenate a file.

Comment: Can you please mark this as answered? I know it's correct, as I tested the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy actually:

```
Loop, Read, C:\FileToReadFrom.txt, C:\FileToAddTo.txt
    FileAppend, `r`n%A_LoopReadLine%
```

This way you only load one line at a time into the RAM.

If you want to know more:
[Loop, Read file contents](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/LoopReadFile.htm)
[FileAppend](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/FileAppend.htm)